# How to create a bar plot with a secondary grouped y-axis in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create an bar graph like that with the following data

```
Satellite   Reference   In-situ Remote sensing
Landsat 8 OLI   Zhu et al., 2022    0.624   0.554325
Landsat 8 OLI   Huang et al., 2021  2.15    1.52
Landsat 5 TM    Huang et al., 2021  2.15    2.3
MODIS           Wu et al., 2022         0.778   0.64
MODIS           Yu et al., 2016         0.0895  0.10546
MODIS           Xu et al., 2010         0.1305  0.11799
Sentinel2A MSI  Huang et al., 2023  0.31    0.41
```

[image]

I have tried the following code, but not expecting what is showing.. Therefore i am seeking help.

```
ggplot(d1, aes(x =pH.value, y =Reference, fill = Type))+
   geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
   facet_wrap(vars(Satellite, Reference), strip.position = "left")
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as you pivot to long format, you can plot this with facets placed on the outside on the left of the plot.

You don't need to flip co-ordinates - you can simply put the values on the x axis:

```r
library(tidyverse)

d1 %>%
  mutate(Satellite = factor(Satellite, rev(unique(Satellite))),
         Reference = factor(Reference, unique(Reference))) %>%
  pivot_longer(`In-situ`:`Remote sensing`) %>%
  mutate(name = factor(name, unique(name))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(value, Reference, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(), width = 0.7) +
  facet_grid(Satellite~., scales = 'free_y', space = 'free_y', switch = 'y') +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = c('#4473c5', '#ec7f2d')) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(text = element_text(family = 'serif'),
        strip.placement = 'outside',
        strip.background = element_rect(color = 'gray', fill = NA),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 10, face = 2),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing.y = unit(0, 'mm'),
        legend.position = 'bottom')
```

[image]

Comment: well...you got the order wrong lol :)

Comment: @Sotos I had to fix that after you pointed it out!

Comment: A nice solution indeed

Comment: I have tried the code. But the following error is showing: Error in `pivot_longer()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `In-situ` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred. @Allan Cameron

Comment: @MajedSajib that's what the column is called in the data you shared. Anyway, try changing the pivot_longer line to `pivot_longer(3:4)`

Comment: @Allan Cameron. Thanks. Its working. You are a gem :D

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to long, do a bar chart and flip it, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(`In.situ`, `Remote.sensing`),
    names_to = "Type",
    values_to = "Value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = interaction(Satellite, Reference, sep = ", "), y = Value, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "Satellite, Reference", y = "Value", fill = "Type")
```

which yields,

[image]

**DATA**

```
structure(list(Satellite = c("Landsat 8 OLI", "Landsat 8 OLI", 
"Landsat 5 TM", "MODIS", "MODIS", "MODIS", "Sentinel2A MSI"), 
    Reference = c("Zhu et al., 2022", "Huang et al., 2021", "Huang et al., 2021", 
    "Wu et al., 2022", "Yu et al., 2016", "Xu et al., 2010", 
    "Huang et al., 2023"), In.situ = c(0.624, 2.15, 2.15, 0.778, 
    0.0895, 0.1305, 0.31), Remote.sensing = c(0.554325, 1.52, 
    2.3, 0.64, 0.10546, 0.11799, 0.41)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```